# Detect div movement nd run function at certain intervals jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have a a div (.wrapper) that moves co ordinates absolutely when the mouse wheel is scrolled, or the user uses his arrow keys/spacebar etc.

At certain points, say when the div.wrapper is -1000 pixels left, Id like a function to happen.

Is there anyway I can check for this without using an interval?

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($('.wrapper').css('left') <= 100 + 'px'){
        alert('foo');   
    } else {
        alert ('bar');  
    };
}, 5000);
```

Comment: How does your div move? The function responsible for the re-positioning would probably the best place to put your condition.

Comment: Are you comparing the return value of `.css('left')` with `100 + 'px'` ??

Comment: I'm using scrollpath @damp http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Comment: You need to treat the `left` values as numbers, `"99px" < "100px"` returns false (both are NaN).

Comment: Yep, use `parseInt()` on the left hand side, and numbers on the right.

Comment: @Damp, you were correct, ive added callbacks into the function responsible, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no event to detect changes in CSS properties. The usual way to do this is to put the call the handler explicitly after updating the `left` property.

You can move the code that changes the value into a separate function:

```
function setLeft(left){
    $('.wrapper').css('left', left);
    if($('.wrapper').css('left') <= 100 + 'px'){
        alert('foo');   
    } else {
        alert ('bar');  
    };
}
```

If you wanted to you could trigger inside the `setLeft` function and put the checking code into an event handler.

Another thing works is creating a wrapper function for `.css` that triggers the event:

```
var originalCssFunction = $.prototype.css;
$.prototype.css = function(){
    originalCssFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    // Check conditions and trigger event
}
```